# Problem creating category tree with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a logic to create unlimited categories, but I want to show the main category and its subcategories with the select box, but I can print only limited to a certain extent.

category db:
`id - name - parent_id`

category model relationships:

```php
public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class, 'parent_id');
    }
```

category controller:

```php
public function categoryTree(): JsonResponse
    {
        $categories = Categories::all();
        $categoriesArr = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category){
            if ($category->parent_id === 0){
                $categoriesArr[] = [
                    'title' => $category->name,
                    'value' => $category->id,
                ];
                continue;
            }
            $categoriesArr[] = [
                'title' => $category->parent->parent_id !== 0 ? $category->parent->parent->name.' > '.$category->parent->name.' > '.$category->name : $category->parent->name.' > '.$category->name,
                'value' => $category->id,
            ];
        }

        return response()->json($categoriesArr);
    }
```

Now I'm getting the following output:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "Real Estate",
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "title": "Vehicle",
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "title": "Vehicle > Car",
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "title": "Vehicle > Car > Bmw",
        "value": 6
    },
    {
        "title": "Car > Bmw > 1 Series",
        "value": 7
    }
]
```

But I want to see an output like this:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "Vehicle > Car > Bmw > 1 Series",
        "value": 7
    }
]
```

Where am I making a mistake? Can you provide me with the correct source? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to write the code I wanted. It might be useful.

```php
    function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $spacing = '', $tree_array = array()) {
        $categories = Categories::where('parent_id' ,'=', $parent_id)->orderBy('parent_id')->get();
        foreach ($categories as $item){
            $parent = $item->parent ? $item->parent->name : '';
            $tree_array[] = ['value' => $item->id, 'title' => $spacing . $item->name] ;
            $tree_array = $this->categoryTree($item->id, $spacing .$item->name.' > ', $tree_array);
        }
        return $tree_array;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if the parent is not 0 you are pulling the name of the grandparent and the name of the parent:

```
$category->parent->parent->name.' > '.$category->parent->name.' > '.$category->name
```

Which is why you only get `Car` and `Bmw` when looking at the `1 Series` category.

Instead you could implement a function like this in the model:

```
public function breadcrumb() {
    $parents = $this->parent_id !== 0? $this->parent->breadcrumb() . " > " : "";
    return $parents . $this->name;
}
```

This will recursively grab the name of all the ancestors.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly where and how to use it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: That would be in the model class for your categories. Most likely `App\Models\Category`

Comment: Property [breadcrumb] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 0):

for parent_id relations use this powerful package [laravel-adjacency-list](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list)

try don't write any code in raw because takes too many time. if there is package in larvel